Angular 17 child routes not works
I have a very simple angular 17 application, and i got problems with routing to child routes. All components are standalone.
this is how my app.routes.ts looks like:
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    pathMatch: "full",
    redirectTo: "home",
  },
  {
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "market",
    component: CampaignListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "device",
        component: DeviceComponent,
      },
    ]
  },
];

this is how my app.component.html looks like:
<div id="container">

  <div id="content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>

</div>

and this is my app.config.ts:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
  ],
};

if i navigate to /market like this:
this.router.navigate(['market']);

it works, and the market page shows up. i add a button to my market.component.html which calls this:
this.router.navigate(['device'], { relativeTo: this.route });

but it the navigation failed with this message:

ERROR Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
'market/device'

i try to add a <router-outlet></router-outlet> to my market.component.html but the same error occurs.
this is index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FuAutomateMeanFe</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <!--<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">-->
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>

What is the problem?

Can you also share your app-routing.module.ts file?

Please, can you share routing module? share also your marketing component.ts file please

@SMVaidhyanathan there is no app-routing.module.ts file.

@DerekRoberts /market points to the CampaignListComponenet. It's full empty: there is only one function :   navigateToPath(path : string) {
this.router.navigate(['device'], { relativeTo: this.route });
}

@solarenqu please share index.html

@NarenMurali updated the question with that.

@solarenqu please share main.ts

@solarenqu could you share github repo instead? it will be faster?

You are missing base href, that might be the problem
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My app</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <base href="/" /> <!-- changed here! -->
  </head>
  <body class="mat-typography">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>


update my question, with the new version of index html.. the same error happens.

the base href url is missing, it must be present, and if it doesnt work try adding <base href="/app/"> if your app is hosted in a subdir.
Also your Path -> if you serving the app from a path other than the root (/), make ensure that the base href conforms with it .
Also Try this so
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },


Then keep base href ="/"
If that does not work do this below.



<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Angular App</title>
  <base href="/app/"> <-- try this instead
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>  <!-- This is the main entry component -->
</body>
</html>






updated the question.

When you navigating device. Use Parent Route/child Route

this.router.navigate(['/market/device']).

Paste in index.html

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>RxjsOperators</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>


tried.. same error happens.

Can you paste the error in comments

I edited the solution. Can you please check.

this.router.navigate(['/market/device']) using this, it's navigate to /market/device but only if i have a  in my market.component.html.. and the content of the market component still on he screen. Is that an option, to reload the content to the original router-outlet?

In Angular, when you navigate to a new route using this.router.navigate(['/market/device']), it will load the content of the device component into the  defined in the market.component.html. The content of the market component will remain on the screen because the market.component.html is still the active template.

Did you understand?
